# pygame - make a stickman jump using arrow keys but goes no higher than 10 units

Tags: python, pygame

the stickman I have is able to move and all, using the arrow keys, and but, when the up arrow key is pressed, I want him to only be able to go about 10 units every time the key is pressed, no matter how long it is pressed for. In other words I want him to jump, and have a limit to how high he can jump. I've tried a couple things but nothing has worked.

```
import pygame

def drawMan(screen,x,y):
    #head
    pygame.draw.ellipse(screen,BLACK,[0+x,0+y,10,10], 0)
    #body
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[4+x,17+y],[4+x,7+y], 2)
    #legs
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[4+x,17+y],[9+x,27+y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[4+x,17+y],[-1+x,27+y], 2)
    #arms
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[4+x,7+y],[8+x,17+y], 2)
    pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,[4+x,7+y],[0+x,17+y], 2)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BORDER = (100,100,100)

pygame.init()

size = (800, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Jump")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.mouse.set_visible(1)

xCoord = 11
yCoord = 463

xSpeed = 0
ySpeed = 0

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xSpeed = -3
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xSpeed = 3
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ySpeed = -3

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                xSpeed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                xSpeed = 0
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                ySpeed = 3


    if xCoord >= 780:
        xSpeed = 0
        xCoord -= 1
    elif xCoord <= 13:
        xSpeed = 0
        xCoord += 1
    elif yCoord > 465:
        ySpeed = 0
        yCoord -= 1
    elif yCoord <= 13:
        ySpeed = 0
        yCoord += 1
    else:
        xCoord += xSpeed
        yCoord += ySpeed


    screen.fill(WHITE)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BORDER, [0,0],[800,0], 20)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BORDER, [0,0],[0,500], 20)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BORDER, [0,500],[800,500], 20)
    pygame.draw.line(screen, BORDER, [800,500],[800,0], 20)


    drawMan(screen,xCoord,yCoord)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

Set a variable that allows him to jump. If the variable isn't True, then the jump key does nothing.

When he jumps, switch the variable to False. Don't reset it until he hits the ground again.

Pseudocode:

```
IF INPUT = "jump" AND can_jump == True THEN
    can_jump = False
    player.jump()
END IF

IF player.y == 0 and can_jump == False THEN
    can_jump = True
END IF
```

Answer (score 0):

dudee i know it is so late but i found out the answer for this and it is a simple thing

```
import pygame as game
import keyboard 
game.init()
dis=game.display.set_mode((1280,720))
state=0
simpclr=(24,24,24)
white=(255,255,255)
posx=5
posy=5
a=0  
jcd=1
clock=game.time.Clock()
while not state:
    for event in game.event.get():
        if event.type==game.QUIT:
            state=1
    dis.fill(white)
    pl=game.Rect(posx,posy,20,20)
    game.draw.rect(dis,simpclr,pl)
    game.display.flip()
    posy+=2
    if keyboard.is_pressed('d'):
        posx+=5
    if jcd<10:
        if keyboard.is_pressed(" "):
            posy-=10
            jcd+=1
    if jcd<50 and jcd>=10:
        jcd+=1
    if jcd==50:
        jcd=1
    if posx==1230:
        posx-=5
    if posy==100:
        posy-=5
    game.display.flip()
    
    clock.tick(60) 
game.quit()
```